# Using micro instance for Elastic MapReduce(EMR) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As amazon charges for an hour even when I use it for minutes. It is getting little expensive to do my school projects  or play around with EMR. As there are micro instances free I want to make use of these to run my mapreduce jobs, there seem to be no option doing so any help in this regard would be great.

Also if that is totally not posibble I wanna know how do I pick  any running instance (probably small instance which EMR gives an option to select via console) for mapreduce job? I am basically planning to run few small instances and get all my small mapreduce jobs use these instances this way I can make most of the money I pay.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I myself fired-up some EC2 instances and tried to run a map reduce job using Elastic MapReduce console and I was not given any options to use the instances already up. Amazon charging on per hour basis is turning out to be bad thing to me at-least.

Please add more info if I am missing or wrong in any way.

PS: I chose to answer my own question as I did not see any help coming and thought this might someday be helpful to someone experimenting with AWS.